# Regex to parse text between '

Tags: c#, regex

I've got the following text:

1. Send Request to BizTalk. CaseID: '2011000264', Title: 'ArchiveDocument Poup - fields.docx', Date: '11.01.2013 13:15:28'
2. Send Request to BizTalk. Title: 'Jallafields.docx', Date: '11.01.2013 13:15:28'

Now I would like to parse out the `Title`. I know this should be pretty straightforward, but I'm struggling, so any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Is it possible for an escaped `'` to exist inside the `Title` text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match your text against:

```
\bTitle: '([^']+)'
```

and capture the first group.

This, of course, supposes that there are no embedded single quotes... If there are, use the `normal* (special normal*)*` "regex pattern" like so (this example assumes such embedded quotes are escaped with a backslash):

```
\bTitle: '([^\\']+(?:\\'[^\\']*)*)'
```

Here, `normal` is `[^\\']` (anything but a backslash or a single quote) and `special` is `\\'` (a backslash followed by a single quote). And this is the kind of thing which the often-used (overused?) lazy quantifiers cannot do ;)

Comment: Could also be written `\bTitle: '(.+?)'` (arguably clearer), or allow empty strings with `\bTitle: '(.*?)'`.

Comment: Yeah, however I prefer avoiding lazy quantifiers -- and they will not capture embedded, quoted single quotes

Answer (score 3):

Just for some Regex/LINQ fun:

```
var s = "Send Request to BizTalk. CaseID: '2011000264', Title: 'ArchiveDocument Poup - fields.docx', Date: '11.01.2013 13:15:28'"   ;
var d = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=[\W])(\w*):\W'([^']*)'").OfType<Match>().ToDictionary (m => m.Groups[1].Value, m=>m.Groups[2].Value);
```

`d` is now

[image]

J̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶h̶o̶p̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶`̶'̶`̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶t̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶.̶.̶.̶

To handle embedded single quotes, just replace the `'([^']+)'` part with `'([^']+(?:\\'[^']*)*)'`, as [fge suggests in his great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14280470/142637):

Comment: See my post for how to "get around" those embedded single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Regex is overkill for this.

Use `string.Split` instead:

```
myString.Split('\'')[3]
```

To break it down a bit - `myString.Split('\'')` will split the string by the passed in character, `'` in this case and return an array of results. I am using the fourth value in the array to retrieve the title - using the array subscript `[3]`.

The above assumes a *very* strict structure to the string.

---

With the second example you posted, it is clear that the above approach will not work.

Comment: This will only work if the layout of that string is always like this.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - No doubt. Difficult to tell from a single example if it isn't so.

Comment: The additional example shows that this is not sufficient; you'll need to key off of `Title` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string like this will work for you

```
String s = " Send Request to BizTalk. CaseID: '2011000264', Title: 'ArchiveDocument Poup - fields.docx', Date: '11.01.2013 13:15:28'";

string[] all = s.Split(',');

foreach( string str in all)
{
  if(str.Contains("Title:"))
  {
     Console.Writeln( (str.Split(':'))[1]);
   }
}
```